# ¿Como detener cualquier pista de audio en JAVA

Tags: java

nuevamente  molestado con mis dudas, tengo el siguiente botón que reproduce un archivo de audio desde un fichero en C: , pero necesito que con otro botón poder  detener dicha pista de audio.
¿Como puedo hacerlo?, de antemano agradezco cualquier ayuda sugerencia o comentario saludos.

```
  private void equipo7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
      String sonido1 = "C:/recursos/equipo10.wav";
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sonido1);
        AudioStream audio1 = new AudioStream(in);
        AudioPlayer.player.start(audio1);
        Arduino.sendData("H");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Window.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, 
 ex);
    }        // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

comparto la solución por si a alguien le sirve XD, después de googlear y googlear y sufrir XD ,

solo hay que declarar una variable dentro de nuestra clase

```
    public AudioStream audio1;
```

en el botón para iniciar la música es el siguiente:

```
    private void equipo7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String sonido1 = "C:/recursos/equipo10.wav";
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sonido1);
     audio1 = new AudioStream(in);
    AudioPlayer.player.start(audio1);

  } catch (Exception ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Window.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }      
   }
```

Y el botón que detiene la canción utiliza el siguiente código:

```
      private void altoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {        
       try {

        AudioPlayer.player.stop(audio1);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Window.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, 
  ex);
    }   
   }
```